# Magento 2, checkout error Copy does not exist

Tags: xampp, magento2, class

Al momento de hacer el checkout la pagina de luma me muestra esto: [image: LUMA]

Cuando me voy a los logs especificamente en exception que es a donde me envia me aparece esta linea de error:

> [2018-06-06 16:57:06] main.CRITICAL: Class Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\SymlinkaMagento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\SymlinkaMagento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy does not exist at C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php:19)"} []

Quisiera saber que hacer...